# stuck in a problem statement which consist of comparing data for two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, dense-rank

PFB the problem statement .
I tried with dense_rank ,keep function but somehow i am not able to crack it. can anyone please help . This is small data set for problem representation . Original tables have several million rows.

scripts for data set:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION (  
    ITEM VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    LOCATION NUMBER(10,0), 
    TRAN_DATE DATE, 
    POST_DATE DATE 
) 


Insert into TRANSACTION (ITEM,LOCATION,TRAN_DATE,POST_DATE) values ('13252099',473,to_date('09-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('09-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into TRANSACTION (ITEM,LOCATION,TRAN_DATE,POST_DATE) values ('13252099',473,to_date('25-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('25-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into TRANSACTION (ITEM,LOCATION,TRAN_DATE,POST_DATE) values ('13252098',470,to_date('09-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('09-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into TRANSACTION (ITEM,LOCATION,TRAN_DATE,POST_DATE) values ('13252098',470,to_date('28-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('28-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));



CREATE TABLE RETAIL_DESC (  
    ITEM VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    LOC NUMBER(10,0), 
    UNIT_RETAIL NUMBER(20,4), 
    ACTION_DATE DATE 
)  


Insert into RETAIL_DESC (ITEM,LOC,UNIT_RETAIL,ACTION_DATE) values ('13252099',473,379.97,to_date('09-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into RETAIL_DESC (ITEM,LOC,UNIT_RETAIL,ACTION_DATE) values ('13252099',473,299.97,to_date('22-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into RETAIL_DESC (ITEM,LOC,UNIT_RETAIL,ACTION_DATE) values ('13252099',473,0.01,to_date('19-AUG-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into RETAIL_DESC (ITEM,LOC,UNIT_RETAIL,ACTION_DATE) values ('13252099',473,379.97,to_date('25-AUG-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into RETAIL_DESC (ITEM,LOC,UNIT_RETAIL,ACTION_DATE) values ('13252098',470,500.18,to_date('08-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into RETAIL_DESC (ITEM,LOC,UNIT_RETAIL,ACTION_DATE) values ('13252098',470,299.97,to_date('09-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into RETAIL_DESC (ITEM,LOC,UNIT_RETAIL,ACTION_DATE) values ('13252098',470,0.01,to_date('19-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into RETAIL_DESC (ITEM,LOC,UNIT_RETAIL,ACTION_DATE) values ('13252098',470,379.97,to_date('24-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into RETAIL_DESC (ITEM,LOC,UNIT_RETAIL,ACTION_DATE) values ('13252098',470,300,to_date('24-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0kSi.png)

Note : I am using oracle 11g database .
1.Table Retail_desc contains unit_retail(price) for a item for a particular location. Action_date is the date at which unit_retail for that item gets updated to new price for that particular location .
an item/location combination can have multiple action_date based on days there price gets updated to new prices .

2. Table transaction contains date (tran_date) on which item was sold from a particular location to a customer (post_date is same as tran_date- can ignore it).

i want to know the unit_retail (price) of the item which was sold to customer in a particular location .

additional comments:
1. for each item/location combination i want to fetch the unit retail which item/loc combination has during time of transaction (tran_date)
2. action_date is date at which unit_retail for item/location changes with new retail.
3. if unit retail changes multiple times on a single action_date , then fetch the retail which has lower price.

Comment: I've removed ambiguous tags. Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: I've formatted your question but you have edited it once again causing a rollback.

Comment: sorry.. i thought ,i had not saved it.. did not see your comment that time

Comment: @Saket . . . I've fixed the formatting of the query.  But the question is totally unclear.  You are communicating to strangers who have no knowledge of  your database or what you are doing.  You have not really done much to explain that.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  i have added more details. PLease let me know if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a subquery with join and `row_number`:

```
select item, loc, unit_retail, tran_date
from (
  select
      r.item, r.loc, r.unit_retail, t.tran_date
    , row_number() over (partition by r.item, r.loc, t.tran_date order by r.action_date desc, r.unit_retail) as rn
  from transaction t
  inner join retail_desc r on
    t.item = r.item
    and t.location = r.loc
  where t.tran_date >= r.action_date
) t
where rn = 1
order by item desc, loc desc, tran_date
```

Output for your sample data:

```
ITEM        LOC     UNIT_RETAIL  TRAN_DATE
13252099    473     379,97       09.07.2018 00:00:00
13252099    473     299,97       25.07.2018 00:00:00
13252098    470     299,97       09.07.2018 00:00:00
13252098    470     300          28.07.2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: @ Kamil G.Thanks for your output .but I am not getting retail for 9-jul-2018 using above query. I need retail of item for particular location during transaction date .

Comment: Try again, I've edited the answer to include tran_date as partition key.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kamil G. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of a correlated subquery for this:

```
select t.*,
       (select min(rd.unit_retail) keep (dense_rank first order by rd.acction_date desc)
        from retail_desc rd
        where rd.loc = t.location and rd.item = t.item and
              rd.action_date <= t.post_date
       ) as unit_retail
from transaction t;
```

However, it might be better to use `lead()` and `join`:

```
select t.*, rd.unit_retail
from transaction t left join
     (select rd.*,
             lead(rd.action_date) over (partition by item, loc order by action_date) as next_action_date
      from retail_desc rd
     ) rd
     on t.location = rd.loc and t.item = rd.item and
        t.post_date >= rd.action_date and
        (t.post_date < rd.next_action_date or rd.next_action_date is null);
```

`dense_rank()` has no obvious connection to this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff . For item 13252098 with tran_date 28-Jul-18
, retail should be 300 (lower retail if there are multiple retails on same action date)

Comment: @Saket . . . It is easier to make the first version work if you have duplicates.  The second method could lead to duplicates.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff i will go with the first version